# Table width is getting messed up

Tags: html, css

please help me with this:

the whole code is given below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="user_list">
   <table id="grd" style="width: 100%;">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <td style="width: 15%;">Name</td>
             <td style="width: 15%;">Age</td>
             <td style="width: 35%;">Address</td>
             <td style="width: 35%;">Office Address</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td>Agnib</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>jhjhhsdj</td>
              <td>wyeruyweryuwe</td>
           <tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

Everything is fine till here. But, once I apply the below css, the width of the columns is getting messed up.

**CSS**

```
#grd thead, #grd tbody
{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Why the width is getting messed up and its becoming smaller in size. I have attached a sample image. Its happening exactly like the below:

[image]

Comment: You do not use `display: block;` for table elements. Apply `table-layout: fixed;` to your `table` if you want width definitions to be properly respected.

Comment: What's the intent of that CSS?

Comment: Actually, I need to make the header of the table as fixed. So, I saw few examples in the internet and found that the thead and tbody need to be made as "display: block" and then I need to put "overflow: auto and a specific height in tbody". So, scrollbar will come only for tbody.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#grd thead, #grd tbody
{
  
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="user_list">
   <table id="grd" style="width: 100%;">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <td style="width: 15%;">Name</td>
             <td style="width: 15%;">Age</td>
             <td style="width: 35%;">Address</td>
             <td style="width: 35%;">Office Address</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td>Agnib</td>
              <td>25</td>
              <td>jhjhhsdj</td>
              <td>wyeruyweryuwe</td>
           <tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
```

or

```
#grd thead, #grd tbody
{

   width: 100%;
}
table
{
    border:1px solid gray;
}
table tr td
{
 border:1px solid gray;   
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/0p8x56c4/)

[DEMO UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/0p8x56c4/1/)

Comment: Actually, I need to make the header of the table as fixed. So, I saw few examples in the internet and found that the thead and tbody need to be made as "display: block" and then I need to put "overflow: auto and a specific height in tbody". So, scrollbar will come only for tbody.

Answer (score 0):

In css file just apply styles to complete table that is `"#grd"`, no need to apply for individual elements like `"#grd thead"` and `"#grd tbody"`.
Try this code once:

```
<table id="grd" style="width: 100%;" border=1>
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td>
         <td style="width: 15%">Name</td>
         <td style="width: 15%">Age</td>
         <td style="width: 35%">Address</td>
         <td style="width: 35%">Office Address</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr><td></td>
          <td style="width: 15%">Agnib</td>
          <td style="width: 15%">25</td>
          <td style="width: 35%">jhjhhsdj</td>
          <td style="width: 35%">wyeruyweryuwe</td>
       <tr>
       <tr><td></td>
          <td style="width: 15%">Agnib</td>
          <td style="width: 15%">25</td>
          <td style="width: 35%">jhjhhsdj</td>
          <td style="width: 35%">wyeruyweryuwe</td>
       <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually, I need to make the header of the table as fixed. So, I saw few examples in the internet and found that the thead and tbody need to be made as "display: block" and then I need to put "overflow: auto and a specific height in tbody". So, scrollbar will come only for tbody.

Comment: Did you applied width for <td> in <tbody> also

Comment: Yes, I applied the same width for <td> in <tbody> as it has been done for <th> in <thead>. I tried the code which you have posted, but still the same issue. I am also trying to apply other jquery plugins for fixed header, but none of them is working for me actually.